# Spark - Generate window with specific keys

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to add a column to my `df_ordored` that identifies windows based on the status column. I want to generate an id for all logs between "open" and "close", as follows:

```
df_ordored = 
+----+---------+------+
|date|word     |status|
+----+---------+------+
|1   |un       |      |
|2   |itnane   |open  |
|3   |tres     |      |
|4   |four     |close |
|4.1 |four     |other |
|5   |fünf     |open  |
|6   |Liù      |null  |
|7   |Sette    |any   |
|8   |vosem    |      |
|9   |Shinchaku|close |
+----+---------+------+
```

```
df_expected =
+----+---------+------+--+
|date|word     |status|id|
+----+---------+------+--+
|1   |un       |      |  |
|2   |itnane   |open  |a |
|3   |tres     |      |a |
|4   |four     |close |a |
|4.1 |four     |other |  |
|5   |fünf     |open  |b |
|6   |Liù      |null  |b |
|7   |Sette    |any   |b |
|8   |vosem    |      |b |
|9   |Shinchaku|close |b |
+----+---------+------+--+
```

Is it possible to do this in dataframe/dataset abstraction and without collecting data on driver ?

Comment: What is the basis for grouping? How do you plan to handle situation where you get multiple `open` before a `close`?

Comment: Also consider the fact that since you are using Spark to process this, your data can be in multiple partitions on multiple worker nodes. To prevent shuffling, you need to sort/order the data and partition the data by some logical group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a window function to generate incremental integers as IDs of open/close sequences:

```py
# Window to compute cumulative sums
cumsum_window = (
    Window
    # .partitionBy('something')  # if you can use a column to partition the data, is a good idea to use it to improve performance in the case of DataFrames with a lot of data/rows
    .orderBy('date')
    .rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)
)

# find row with status open
df = df.withColumn('is_open', F.when(F.col('status') == 'open', 1).otherwise(0))

# mark both open and close, with 1 and -1 respectively
df = df.withColumn('is_open_close', F.when(F.col('status') == 'close', -1).otherwise(F.col('is_open')))

# A sequence is composed by rows between open and close (included).
# So, row belongs to a sequence if one of the following holds:
#    1. have close status or 1 in the cumulative sum 
#    2. its cumulative sum of the column is_open_close is 1
#    IS_OPEN_CLOSE: 0 0 0 ... 1 (open) 0 0 ... 0 -1 (close) 0 1 (open) ...
#    CUMSUM:        0 0 0 ... 1 (open) 1 1 ... 1  0 (close) 0 1 (open) ...
df = df.withColumn('is_in_sequence', (F.col('status') == 'close') | (F.sum('is_open_close').over(cumsum_window).cast(T.BooleanType())))

# Compute an id for rows in a sequence as the ordinal of their correspondent
# open in the is_open column. Use the cumulative sum of is_open to compute it.
#    IS_OPEN: 0 0 0 ... 1 (open) 0 0 ... 0  0 (close) 0 1 (open) ...
#    CUMSUM:  0 0 0 ... 1 (open) 1 1 ... 1  1 (close) 1 2 (open) ...
# Assign the just created ID only to rows belonging to a sequence
df = df.withColumn('sequence_id', F.when(F.col('is_in_sequence'), F.sum('is_open').over(cumsum_window)))

# remove temporary columns
df = df.drop('is_open')
df = df.drop('is_open_close')
df = df.drop('is_in_sequence')
```

This is what you get:

```bash
+----+---------+------+-----------+
|date|     word|status|sequence_id|
+----+---------+------+-----------+
|   1|       un|  null|       null|
|   2|   itnane|  open|          1|
|   3|     tres|  null|          1|
|   4|     four| close|          1|
| 4.1|     four| other|       null|
|   5|     fünf|  open|          2|
|   6|      Liù|  null|          2|
|   7|    Sette|   any|          2|
|   8|    vosem|  null|          2|
|   9|Shinchaku| close|          2|
+----+---------+------+-----------+
```

If you are using a partition column in the window, obviously the ID of a sequence will be the pair composed by the `sequence_id` and that column. You can easily translate it into an overall unique ID by combining them. For instance, suppose that your DataFrame is the following one:

```bash
+-------------------+---------+------+
|               date|     word|status|
+-------------------+---------+------+
|2022-01-10 12:00:00|       un|  null|
|2022-01-10 13:00:00|   itnane|  open|
|2022-01-10 14:00:00|     tres|  null|
|2022-01-10 15:00:00|     four| close|
|2022-01-10 16:00:00|     four| other|
|2022-01-10 17:00:00|     fünf|  open|
|2022-01-10 18:00:00|      Liù|  null|
|2022-01-10 18:00:00|    Sette|   any|
|2022-01-10 20:00:00|    vosem|  null|
|2022-01-10 21:00:00|Shinchaku| close|
|2022-01-13 09:00:00|       ve|  null|
|2022-01-13 10:00:00|      col|  open|
|2022-01-13 11:00:00|     bias|  null|
|2022-01-13 12:00:00|       no| close|
+-------------------+---------+------+
```

and you want to partition by day, then you can use the following window:

```py
cumsum_window = (
    Window
    .partitionBy(F.date_trunc('day', 'date'))
    .orderBy('date')
    .rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)
)
```

and add the following piece of code as final step:

```py
df = df.withColumn(
    'unique_sequence_id',
    F.when(
        F.col('sequence_id').isNotNull(),
        F.concat_ws('_', F.date_format('date', 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'sequence_id')
    )
)
```

This is the result:

```bash
+-------------------+---------+------+-----------+------------------+
|               date|     word|status|sequence_id|unique_sequence_id|
+-------------------+---------+------+-----------+------------------+
|2022-01-10 12:00:00|       un|  null|       null|              null|
|2022-01-10 13:00:00|   itnane|  open|          1|      2022-01-10_1|
|2022-01-10 14:00:00|     tres|  null|          1|      2022-01-10_1|
|2022-01-10 15:00:00|     four| close|          1|      2022-01-10_1|
|2022-01-10 16:00:00|     four| other|       null|              null|
|2022-01-10 17:00:00|     fünf|  open|          2|      2022-01-10_2|
|2022-01-10 18:00:00|      Liù|  null|          2|      2022-01-10_2|
|2022-01-10 18:00:00|    Sette|   any|          2|      2022-01-10_2|
|2022-01-10 20:00:00|    vosem|  null|          2|      2022-01-10_2|
|2022-01-10 21:00:00|Shinchaku| close|          2|      2022-01-10_2|
|2022-01-13 09:00:00|       ve|  null|       null|              null|
|2022-01-13 10:00:00|      col|  open|          1|      2022-01-13_1|
|2022-01-13 11:00:00|     bias|  null|          1|      2022-01-13_1|
|2022-01-13 12:00:00|       no| close|          1|      2022-01-13_1|
+-------------------+---------+------+-----------+------------------+
```